# hosting a linux web application over windows

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

I'm using virtualbox and created an ubuntu virtual machine over vm. I installed some web application on ubuntu.

I can access the app 'http://localhost:9999' in linux but when i switched to the windows side, i can not access the url. the network is shared over nat. How can i access that web app someway?

Comment: Should go to Superuser or ServerFault, I'd say. Answer depends on the VM software you're using.

Comment: there are tags called virtualization/virtualbox. that's why this question asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by using localhost, that's for sure. If using the IP address doesn't work, you may need to configure the application (webserver?) to bind to the global address.

(sidenote: really a serverfault question?)